# How to access functions just defined in literal in other function in same literal?

Tags: javascript

Supposed I have *bike* objects with a property *{ retired: true }* and I want to prepare some filters, like *functioning* and *notFunctioning*:

```
var BikeChecker = {
  functioning: function(bike) {
    return (bike.retired != true);
  },
  notFunctioning: function(bike) {
    return !functioning(bike);
  };
```

How do I access *functioning* from within *notFunctioning* thus avoiding to write *notFunctioning* from scratch?

I want to avoid:

```
notFunctioning: function(bike) {
  return (bike.retired == true);
}
```

And please, do not suggest to do *!functioning(bike)* instead of defining *notFunctioning(bike)* (because angular-js does not allow me to negate a functioning passed to the filter 'filter')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly. You can't directly refer to an object literal that doesn't yet exist.

A frequent pattern is to use a factory (an IIFE), so that your object is stored in a variable that you can refer to :

```
var BikeChecker = (function(){
    var b = {};
    b.functioning = function(bike) {
      return (bike.retired != true);
    };
    b.notFunctioning = function(bike) {
      return !b.functioning(bike);
    }
    return b;
})();
```

Another pattern would be to use a prototype so that you can refer to `this` but I wouldn't suggest to use it for a singleton.